# Objective-C NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData issue changes the format of the JSON text

Tags: objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I run this sample of code

```
 NSString *st =@"{ \"Hello\" : [ {\"m\":\"m\"} ] }";

NSDictionary * dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[st dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
```

and i get the output in dic:

```
{
    Hello =     (
                {
            m = m;
        }
    );
}
```

replace the square bracket "[" to "(" ,, Why ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON uses square brackets `[ ... ]` for an array, see http://json.org.

The `description` method of `NSArray` uses parentheses `( ... )` to print an array.
That format is described in [Old-Style ASCII Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html).

You cannot expect the output to be equal. As another example, strings in JSON are always enclosed in quotation marks: `"m"`, and the "Old-Style ASCII Property Lists" format
omits the quotation marks for purely alphanumeric strings without spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This hasn't actually change anything, it's just a question of formatting. It's customary in Cocoa and ObjC to represent arrays in `()` instead of the `[]` used in javascript. For example, try:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

And you will see:

```
2014-02-02 10:47:41.468 Untitled[2773:507] (  
    one,  
    two,  
    three  
)
```

`NSArray` just uses parens to describe itself.